# standard delete button on a custom vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a object AccountPlan. I hv created a page which overrides new edit and clone button. Now i created a new page to override with view button. But now edit delete and clone buttons are not appearing on my view page. I want the standard buttons (edit,delete and clone ) to appear on my view page. How should i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit" id="editButton" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.ProductService__c.delete,ProductService__c.id,[retURL=ProductService__c.Opportunity__c])}" value="Delete" id="deleteButton" />
             <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.ProductService__c.Clone,ProductService__c.id)}" value="Clone" id="cloneButton"/>  
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

In my case I used a customobject called productservice__c as a name.

Comment: thanks. For delete i want a pop up asking "are you sure ?". what should i do for that ?